# Why led isn't blinking when i press the button?

Tags: stm32, stm32f4

I am tring to write a code for stm32f401cb which will blink the led when i press the led and when i leave pressing the button,it will turn out the led.I have set channel ahb1 which connects to port a and b in my microprocessor f401cb and i chose input type pull down in port a and led is connected to port b.

But my led is not blinking in anyway.

where is my mistake you think?

My led is not blinking when i press the button.it is always turned out

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"

void ahb1_config(void) {
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB,ENABLE);
}

void gpio_config(void) {
    GPIO_InitTypeDef gpio_init;
    gpio_init.GPIO_Mode=0x00;
    gpio_init.GPIO_Pin=GPIO_Pin_0 ;
    gpio_init.GPIO_OType=0x00;
    gpio_init.GPIO_PuPd=0x02;
    gpio_init.GPIO_Speed=0x03;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA,&gpio_init);

    gpio_init.GPIO_Mode=GPIO_Mode_OUT;
    gpio_init.GPIO_Pin=GPIO_Pin_0 ;
    gpio_init.GPIO_OType=GPIO_OType_PP;
    gpio_init.GPIO_Speed=GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB,&gpio_init);


}







int main(void)
{







  while (1)
  {
        ahb1_config();
        gpio_config();
        if (GPIO_ReadInputDataBit(GPIOA,GPIO_Pin_0)) {
            GPIO_SetBits(GPIOB,GPIO_Pin_0);
        }
        else {
            GPIO_ToggleBits(GPIOB,GPIO_Pin_0);
        }

  }
}
```

[image: proteus circuit image is here]

Answer (score 1):

Move the config functions outside the while loop.

The main problem however is that you have no delay, so you are toggling the LED as fast as the processor can, which is faster than your eye can see.

Comment: From a hardware point of view, your symbol is missing the power supply pins.  If the power supply is 3.3V, that is too much for a red LED without a series resistor.  Also did you mean to connect the switch to all of those 10 pins?

Comment: no.i am just using the 0(zero) pins for a and b ports